# How to set up two Gnome sessions to start automatically

Tags: gnome, gdm

**Is it possible to set up two different Gnome sessions to be started at boot time?**

As it is now (and by default in any Ubuntu installation) a gdm login screen is presented after a few minutes of booting. After I log in, it's possible to use the "Switch user" functionality and have a second Gnome session running (for another reason). Then, both sessions are accessible by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>.

Moreover it would be great if both sessions used different settings (different users) for automatic logging in.

Answer (score 1):

I've been researching and the closest I could get to, your answer is to after have one user logged in, log the other user (almost) automatically.

1) Open Gnome Session Properties

```
gnome-session-properties
```

2) and add this to a start up

```
gdmflexiserver
```

I will continue my research and post here if I find something else.

Comment: I recall doing something like this years and years ago (befor ubuntu even existed) . These days  one could resort to starting 2 X sessions from the /etc/rc.local script.